# Is the word "broken" here adjective or verb or both?

Tags: grammar, articles, verbs, adjectives, auxiliary-verbs

I have three sentences:

A: This is a *broken* window.
B: This window is *broken*.
C: This is *broken* window.

I know *break* is a verb, because it represents action. But *broken* also adds meaning to noun *window*, so it should act like adjective. I also doubt the third sentence cannot be used in any context as it is ungrammatical.

Comment: It's an adjective in all your examples. The window is in a broken state from prior breaking. Incidentally, C is ungrammatical since "broken window" requires one of the articles "a" or "the".

Answer (score 4):

As Cambridge dictionary explains, when it describes something damaged, [**broken**](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/broken) can be both predicative and attributive adjectives.

> *1. He put a sheet of plastic over the broken window.* (attributive)
>
> *2. She had an X-ray to see if any of her ribs were broken.* (predicative)

Regarding the third sentence, you need to use an article before the adjective.

---

However, you can consider ***be+broken*** as a passive construction, but in the passives the agents are the key elements. In other words, you use passives when the agent is more important than the subject. Needless to say that, be itself, is a linking verb which can be followed by adjectives.

I think if your examples were with more details, then it would be more easy to judge them:

> - This window is broken by little pressure. I don't like it! (broken is a verb)
> - This window is broken though it couldn't be discerned easily. (broken is an adjective)

Comment: So shall I take it as that in #2 _broken_ is not verb?

Comment: @user31782 I think so (, but I am not a native). I'm saying that because in that sentence you primarily want to describe the window. Thus, it's more likely to be a an adjective which follows a linking verb, "is".

Comment: You say that in my third sentence I must use an article before the adjective, but on Cambridge page they used it as: "_Be careful - there's **[]** broken glass on the kitchen floor._"

Comment: "there is broken glass" is different from "this is {a/the} broken window". The former seems to be uncountable!

Comment: Yes Cardinal, that's spot on! Btw, @user31782, *glass* would be countable if you are referring to the object you use drink.